unable to solve a question on validating a string using regex in python
These are the conditions:

It must start with a 4, 5 or 6.
It must contain exactly 16 digits.
It must only consist of digits (0-9).
It may have digits in groups of 4, separated by one hyphen "-".
It must NOT use any other separator like ' ' , '_', etc.
It must NOT have 4 or more consecutive repeated digits.

this is my code, all cases are giving 'Invalid' output.
import re
for _ in range(int(input())):
    if re.search(r'^(?<=[4-6])(?!.*(.)(-?\1){3}.*)(\d{4})(-?\d{4}){3}$', input()):
        print('Valid')
    else: print('Invalid')

sample input:
The first line (6) is the number of testcases
6
4123456789123456
5123-4567-8912-3456
61234-567-8912-3456
4123356789123456
5133-3367-8912-3456
5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456

sample output:
Valid
Valid
Invalid
Valid
Invalid
Invalid


This can never work ^(?<=[4-6]) I think you mean a positive lookahead like ^(?=[456]) See https://regex101.com/r/k6p29w/1 Do you mean that 6 is valid?

Is this a school assignment?  Because that's going to be extremely difficult if you are required to ONLY use a regex.  Doing this as a Python function would not be too bad, but you'll use things other than regexes.  And, by the way, the first entry is invalid because it doesn't have 16 digits.

No, "6" is not valid.  It violates rule #2.

Why would 5123-4567-8912-3456 be invalid and 61234-567-8912-3456 valid? Are you missing a value in the expected output as there are 7 input values.

@TimRoberts this isn't a school assignment but i was practicing regex on hackerrank, which is why i'm trying to do it using only regex. also the first entry (aside from the 6 which is the number of entries) is 16 digits

So the 6 is not a value that should be matched by a regex correct?

@Thefourthbird sorry about the confusion, the first number (6) is the number of test cases. 6 is not valid, i  misunderstood your question earlier. the cases start from the second line

@rushi Did you enter the updated regex from my comment above? https://regex101.com/r/k6p29w/1

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a Q&A site, but there's no question here. We're not here to debug your code for you, if that's what you're looking for. Please read [ask]. You might want to read Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question? Instead, you might try debugging your regex. I've never done it myself, but I found some resources that look helpful: How can I debug a regular expression in Python?, How do you debug a regex?

@Thefourthbird i just did, it worked. i dont understand why we cannot use a lookbehind though?

@rushi Because you are at the start of the string with ^ and then you assert that there is either 4, 5 or 6 directly to the left with ^(?<=[4-6]) which can not match. The 4, 5 or 6 should be to the right

@Thefourthbird what about if i wrote it without a ^ ?

The thing is that if you write it without ^ you assert [4-6] to the left, but in the assertions after it (?!.*(.)(-?\1){3}.*) you want to include that first [4-6] right? And you want to match 16 digits as well. Remember that the assertions are from the current position.

@Thefourthbird oh i got it! thankyou so much for taking the time out :)

Since you are trying to validate a whole string, I suggest to use re.fullmatch in place of re.search. Note that with re.fullmatch anchors ^ and $ become implicit since the pattern has to describe the whole string.

@TimRoberts i understand your solution, i dont understand why we would prefer it over using regex though?

@CasimiretHippolyte oh thankyou! ill keep that in mind :)

Is the string 51234567-8912-3456 valid or invalid ?

Why?  (1) I don't believe a single regex can do this task.  (2) The simple solution is easier to understand.  Your regex would REQUIRE comments for future programmers to know what you did.  (3) Regexes are cute, but they are not always the high performance answer.

There's an old saying.  "I had a problem.  So, I created a regex for it.  Now I have two problems."

If you want to use only regex and you can use multiple patterns, I would express each of your rules in the following patterns and check all the patterns for each input:
import re

_four_consecutive_digits = r'(?:(\d)(?:(?!(\1{3}|\1{2}\-\1|\1\-\1{2}|\-\1{3})))-?){16}'

rules = {
'Starts with 4, 5, or 6': r'^[456]',
'contains exactly 16 digits': r'^(?:\D*\d){16}$',
'must consist of only digits (and hyphens)': r'^[\d\-]+$',
'if hyphenated, must be groups of 4': r'^(\d{16}|\d{4}(-\d{4}){3})$',
# "must not use other separators" covered by rule 3
'must not have 4 consecutive digits': _four_consecutive_digits
}

def check_rules(s: str) -> bool:
    for rule, pattern in rules.items():
        if not re.match(pattern, s):
            return False
    return True

Testing the inputs:
inputs = '''\
4123456789123456
5123-4567-8912-3456
61234-567-8912-3456
4123356789123456
5133-3367-8912-3456
5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456'''.splitlines()


expected = [True, True, False, True, False, False]

actual = []
for s in inputs:
    result = check_rules(s)
    actual.append(result)

assert actual == expected, f'{actual=} {expected=}'

It may be possible to combine all these rules together into one expression, but I'm not sure. But keeping each rule separate would also let you provide specific validation errors.
For example, you could display the rule that caused validation to fail:
# modify to return the failure reason
def check_rules(s: str) -> tuple[str, bool]:
    for rule, pattern in rules.items():
        if not re.match(pattern, s):
            return f'failed: {rule}', False
    return 'valid', True

for s in inputs:
    reason, passed = check_rules(s)
    print(s.ljust(25), reason)

output
4123456789123456          valid
5123-4567-8912-3456       valid
61234-567-8912-3456       failed: if hyphenated, must be groups of 4
4123356789123456          valid
5133-3367-8912-3456       failed: must not have 4 consecutive digits
5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456 failed: must consist of only digits (and hyphens)


About the _four_consecutive_digits subpattern, you don't need to repeat it 16 times, only 13 times suffice. Also note that the string '4567456745674۰۱۲' passes all the tests (due to the \d shorthand in unicode mode).

Good point. The rule must consist of only digits  should probably use [0-9] instead of \d @CasimiretHippolyte

Yes, but you could also use the flag re.A (aka re.ASCII) to limit \d to ascii digits.

This is not a hard task for simple parsing, but finding 4-in-a-row while allowing dashes in the middle in the proper sequence may be beyond what a reasonable single regex can do.  You need too much state.
data = """\
4123456789123456
5123-4567-8912-3456
61234-567-8912-3456
4123356789123456
5133-3367-8912-3456
5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456""".splitlines()

def valid(s):
    if s[0] not in '456':
        return False
    if len(s) not in (16,19):
        return False
    if any(c not in '0123456789-' for c in s):
        return False
    if '-' in s:
        parts = s.split('-')
        if not all(len(p)==4 for p in parts):
            return False
        s = s.replace('-','')
    if not s.isdigit():
        return False
    count = 0
    clast = ''
    for c in s:
        if c == clast:
            count += 1
            if count >= 4:
                return False
        else:
            count = 1
            clast = c
    return True

for s in data:
    print(s,valid(s))

Output:
4123456789123456 True
5123-4567-8912-3456 True
61234-567-8912-3456 False
4123356789123456 True
5133-3367-8912-3456 False
5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456 False


Solution with regex (Regex101):
import re

test_cases = """\
4123456789123456
5123-4567-8912-3456
61234-567-8912-3456
4123356789123456
5133-3367-8912-3456
5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456"""

for t in test_cases.splitlines():
    print(f"{t:<30}", end=" ")
    m = re.match(r"(?!.*(\d)(?:-?\1){3})[456]\d{3}(?:-?\d{4}){3}$", t)
    print("Valid" if m else "Invalid")

Prints:
4123456789123456               Valid
5123-4567-8912-3456            Valid
61234-567-8912-3456            Invalid
4123356789123456               Valid
5133-3367-8912-3456            Invalid
5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456      Invalid

